# covariance of integral of Brownian

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

What is the covariance of the process $X(t) = \int_0^t B(u)\,du$ where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion? i.e., I wish to find $E[X(t)X(s)]$, for $0<s<t<\infty$. Any ideas?

Thanks you very much for your help!

Answer (score 8):

$$\mathbb E(X(t)X(s))=\int_0^t\int_0^s\mathbb E(B(u)B(v))\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du=\int_0^t\int_0^s\min\{u,v\}\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du$$
**Edit:** As @TheBridge noted in a comment, the exchange of the order of integration is valid by Fubini theorem, since $\mathbb E(|B(u)B(v)|)\leqslant\mathbb E(B(u)^2)^{1/2}\mathbb E(B(v)^2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{uv}$, which is uniformly bounded on the domain $[0,t]\times[0,s]$ hence integrable on this domain.

Comment: @ did : probably the shortest possible beautiful answer but it lacks a little justsification of the use of Fubini's theorem ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much :) That's exactly what I did and I got $\frac{1}{2}s^2t$, but shouldn't it give me something "symmetric"? I mean, if I exchange $s$ by $t$ then get the same answer? Since covariance matrices are symmetric. Thanks :)

Comment: Once you assume that $s\lt t$, the setting is not symmetric with respect to $(s,t)$ anymore. I guess your formula is really $\frac12\min(s,t)^2\max(s,t)$, which is symmetric (but I did not check this was indeed the result).

Comment: @TheBridge Right, post modified. (Unrelated: beware of the space between `@` and `user's name`.)

Answer (score 2):

As @Did explained in his answer, the covariance of the integrated Brownian motion is obtained by integrating the covariance of the usual Brownian motion. However, he refrained from computing said integral, which led to some confusion in the comments.

To evaluate the integral, we make use of the identity $\min\{u,v\}=u-1[v<u](u-v)$. Recall that we are assuming $0<s<t<\infty$. Therefore
$$
\int_0^s\int_0^t \min\{u,v\}\ dv \ du=\int_0^s\int_0^t u\ dv \ du-\int_0^s\int_0^u u-v\ dv \ du=\frac{ts^2}{2}-\frac{s^3}{6}.
$$
Note that @martin's calculation in the comments is incorrect: it consists of just the first term above, and comes from assuming that $u\leq v$ throughout the region of integration (which is false).

Comment: I think this might be missing a term? And should be $- \frac{t^3}{3}
- \frac{(t')^2}{3}
+ \frac{t^2 s}{2}
+ \frac{t (s)^2}{2}$? Basically if you draw the chart you should have a square with two triangles and then a rectangular region.

Comment: @mathtick No, the result is correct, which you can check by dissecting the inner integral in the case where $v<u$ and $v>u$, giving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

$$E[x(s)x(t)] = \int_0^t \int_0^s E\bigg(B(u)B(v)\bigg)dvdu$$
holds true for the linearity of expection. It seems Fubini's theorem in the arguement of @ did comes to treat expectation operator as integral which different from the theory in the context of measure theory which proposes
$$E(X)=E_{P1}\big(E_{P2}(X)\big)=E_{P2}\big(E_{P1}(X)\big)$$
if $X$ is jointly measurable and either nonnegative or jointly integrable.

Comment: This adds nothing new to Did's answer, posted six years ago.