# Contradiction on equality with stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I want to compute $E[∫_0^tB_u \, du ∫_0^sB_u \, du]$ and I know from another source that should be equal to $ts^2/2$.
But when I try to compute it like:

$$\begin{align}
& E\left[(tB_t- \int_0^tu \, dB_u)(sB_s- \int_0^su \, dB_u)\right] \\
& =E[tsB_t B_s ] – E\left[tB_t \int_0^su \, dB_u\right] – E\left[sB_s \int_0^tu \, dB_u\right] + E\left[\int_0^tu \, dB_u ∫_0^su dB_u\right] \\
& = ts^2 - (ts^2)/2 - s^3/2 + s^3/3\text{ and this is not }ts^2/2.
\end{align}
$$

I know I took the long way around approach but I still should obtain the same answer.

Comment: "I know from another source that should be equal to ts2/2"... Sure about that? Which source?

Comment: The source is a similar question on this very site, but the answer was made inverting integration and the average.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: This one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241618/covariance-of-integral-of-brownian

Comment: Check the comment: `but I did not check this was indeed the result`.

Comment: This might be the time to close the present question.