# Covariance of two integrated Brownian motions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, brownian-motion

I have a question that is similar to the one  here:
[covariance of integral of Brownian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241618/covariance-of-integral-of-brownian), but the answer that I come up with does not match what the book claims the answer is.

> Given that $$X_t = \int_0^t \frac{B_u}{u}du,$$ where $B$ is standard Brownian motion, and that $t\leq s$, what is $E[X_tX_s]$?

I have that $$E[X_tX_s] = \int_0^t\int_0^s\frac{u\wedge v}{uv}\,dv\,du.$$ This I can justify by Fubini, Holder's inequality and the fact that $E[B_uB_v] = u\wedge v$. Then,

$$\int_0^t\int_0^s\frac{u\wedge v}{uv}\,dv\,du = \int_0^t\int_0^u\frac{ v}{uv}\,dv\,du +  \int_0^t\int_u^s\frac{u}{uv}\,dv\,du$$

I compute the sum of the two integrals on the RHS as $t + t\ln{s} - \int_0^t\ln{u}\,du$. The last integral here does not even converge. I must have done something wrong obviously because I have just shown that this expression was integrable before applying Fubini (furthermore, there is no logarithmic term in the given answer) but I don't see where I am going wrong.

Edit: As Tom-Tom pointed out the RHS converges to $t\ln{\frac{s}{t}}$ but the resulting answer is still not what is given in the book, which is $2t-t^2+st$.

Comment: Actually, $\int_\varepsilon^t\ln u\,\mathrm du=t\ln t-t-\varepsilon\ln\varepsilon+\varepsilon\xrightarrow[\varepsilon\to0]{}t\ln t-t$. So in principle the integral converges and the result is $t\ln\frac st$.

Comment: @muaddib $E[\lvert B_uB_v\rvert] \leq (E[B_u^2])^{1/2}(E[B_v^2])^{1/2} = \sqrt{uv}$ by Holder. If I then integrate $\int_0^t\int_0^s\frac{\sqrt{uv}}{uv}\,dv\,du$, I get $4\sqrt{st}$.

Comment: "As Tom-Tom pointed out the last integral converges but the resulting answer is still not what is given in the book." Since the convergence is acknowledged and the question is now to check the result, please show the result you got and the result in your book.

Comment: The trouble is that, in the last double integral on the RHS, the inner integral $\int_u^s$ should appear **only when** $u<s$ and that the outer integral is from $u=0$ to $u=t$ with $t>s$, hence this should be decomposed into the sum of the contributions from $u=0$ to $u=s$ and from $u=s$ to $u=t$.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much.